# Отключить обязательность e-mail

Tags: wordpress

Возможно ли на сайте вордпресс глобально отключить обязательность заполнения поля e-mail во всех формах, и даже в тех которые установленны различными плагинами. Т.Е чтобы поля e-mail можно было незаполнять и сайт пропускал тебя к следующему шагу.

Comment: Ручками выпиливать нужно из каждого плагина.

Comment: нет, волшебной палочки тут не будет